# jquery how select element by inverse name attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags, inverse

I want to select items by reverse attribute name only:

I select with a[^safe] or a[!safe], wrong

My HTML:

```
<ul>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
</ul>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$("a[^safe]").each(function(){
    $(this).css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid gold"});
});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpr4tow1/1/

Comment: You're looking for elements without a safe attribute?  `$('a:not([safe])')` or `$('a').not('[safe]')`

Comment: Side note; you do not need the explicit each.  `css()`, and most jQuery methods, perform an implicit each over the result stack

Comment: Thank you @Taplar, already solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` selector to make the modification, or just make a css rule for it and do without the javascript all together.

Though, if you choose the pure css way, you'll most likely want to scope the selector down so it is not so global.

```js
$('a:not([safe])').addClass('not-safe')
```

```css
.not-safe {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
</ul>
```

```css
a:not([safe]) {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
  <a safe href="#">Link Base</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your valuable help. :)